# Tokenize char* variable in c while creating a simple FTP server

Tags: c++, char, whitespace, tokenize, strtok

So I have a variable buff which gets its value from the read() function and I want to be able to tokenize it using whitespace. I have read upon the strtok() function but have no clue how to use this for this situation.

```
 char *buff = new char[256];
 char *command = new char[5];
 for (;;) 
 {
    int ConnectFD = accept(SocketFD, NULL, NULL);
    if (0 > ConnectFD) 
    {
      perror("accept failed");
      close(SocketFD);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

     send(ConnectFD, "220\n", 4, 0);

     read(ConnectFD, buff, 256);
    while(1)
    {
      memcpy(&command, &buff, 4);
      if(strncmp(command, "USER", 5))
      {
          send(ConnectFD, "230\n", 4, 0);
      }
```

I want to tokenize it so I can use the arguments sent after the command seperated by a space.

Comment: I'm afraid you aren't ready for tokenizing. `read` will read **up to** the number of bytes specified by the third parameter. You might not get any bytes. You must accept and test the return value to know how much was read. Read until you have at least one line of instructions before parsing. After that, since this is tagged C++, [consider using `std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) rather than `strtok`.

Comment: how would I read until I at least one line of instruction?

Comment: Read, write into buffer, scan he buffer for an end of line. If you get one, process. If you don't read more and scan the new stuff for end of line. Repeat as necessary.